# How to wrap a bootstrap button inside a react component (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

What I want to do is to take a bootstrap component, let's say a Bootstrap button, and wrap it inside a react component using Typescript.

I want to pass parameters (such as width, height, colour, etc.) in the react component which would then modify the Bootstrap button wrapped in the component accordingly.

Basically, I want that the height, width, colour options in the Bootstrap button are variable which I can change according to parameters of the react component.

Can someone please give me a basic example of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a file in a components folder,

.../components/Button.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

type buttonType = {
label: string;
};


const Button = ({ label, btnStyle}: buttonType ) => (
  <button
    className={btnStyle}
  >
    {label}
  </button>
);

export default Button;
```

Then in another file, import the button and use it like this.

```
<Button label="My Text" btnStyle="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
```